# generics behaves weird with inner class with instanceOf check

Tags: java, generics, intellij-idea

See the code

```
public class AdnanTestClass<T> {

    public void doForTest(Object o){
        if (o instanceof TestInnerClass){

        }
    }

    private class TestInnerClass{

    }
}
```

This piece of code gives compile time error in `doForTest` method. it says illegal generics types.

if I qualify the inner class with outer class like this

```
    if (o instanceof AdnanTestClass.TestInnerClass){

    }
```

This compiles perfectly fine.

`if (o instanceof TestInnerClass)` also works if I remove `<T>` from my class declaration.

I am not sure what I missing here. Is there a potential problem qualifying with outer class. Can someone point out? I did this test with intellij idea 14 with Java 8.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [JLS §15.20.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2):

> It is a compile-time error if the ReferenceType mentioned after the
>   instanceof operator does not denote a reference type that is reifiable
>   (§4.7).

Now, your first code:

```
if (o instanceof TestInnerClass)
```

is equivalent to:

```
if (o instanceof AdnanTestClass<T>.TestInnerClass)
```

But, since `AdnanTestClass<T>` is not reifiable (see [JLS §4.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.7)), 
`AdnanTestClass<T>.TestInnerClass` is also not reifiable, and hence that is not a valid expression. Relevant quote from that JLS section:

> For example, if a generic class `X<T>` has a generic member class 
>   `Y<U>`, then the type `X<?>.Y<?>` is reifiable because `X<?>` is 
>   reifiable and `Y<?>` is reifiable. The type `X<?>.Y<Object>` is not 
>   reifiable because `Y<Object>` is not reifiable.

Instead, if you change that to:

```
// unbounded wildcard
if (o instanceof AdnanTestClass<?>.TestInnerClass)

// or, raw type
if (o instanceof AdnanTestClass.TestInnerClass)
```

that will become reifiable, and hence is valid expression.

Comment: fantastic  **Refiable Explanation** !!!

Answer (score 3):

In your case `o instanceof TestInnerClass` syntax is actually a shorthand of `o instanceof AdnanTestClass<T>.TestInnerClass` but since type parameter (the `<T>` part) is erased at runtime, that short hand is no longer valid, hence Java compiler gives you error instead and asked to explicitly drop the type parameter.

Here's more information about generics type erasure: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Answer (score 2):

this

```
if (o instanceof TestInnerClass){
```

is equal to

```
if (o instanceof AdnanTestClass<T>.TestInnerClass){
```

so you can't actully check `instanceof` when it's not clearly said what outer class's `T` is.
Your second piece of code ignores `T`, it's undefined but then, for an inner class, it is already unambiguous

I think that you can solve it like this:

```
private class TestInnerClass<T> {
```

Comment: @NeerajJain umm.... no